# NGINX: How to redirect from img/file.jpg to public/img/file.jpg

Tags: nginx, redirect, nginx-config, nginx-location, public-folders

I have an nginx configuration like this:

```sh
server{
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
server_name _;
root /var/www/all-my-projects;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    autoindex on;
    autoindex_localtime on;
    autoindex_exact_size off;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass $php_fastcgi_pass;
    fastcgi_index /index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    # regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}

# These are the locations I'm havin' trouble
location /project {
    try_files $uri @store-deprecated;
}
location @project {
    rewrite /project/(.*)$ /project/public/index.php?_url=/$1 last;
}
}
```

but when I go to `localhost/project` the images on the browser doesn't load on any view.
I know I rewrote when I go to the `project` folder, it redirects to `project/public/index.php` and run the site.

I put the images in the html like this:

```html
<img src="img/image.png">
```

How can I rewrite the `public/img/` folder to access all the images by typing `localhost/project/img/image.png`?

Same thing with a `css` and `js` folders and a `favicon.ico`

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
  rewrite ~ ^(/img/.*) /public$1 break;
}
```